# How to Access Microsoft PowerApp

Tags: ms-office, powerapps

I am using Microsoft Power App for the first time.  I created a rudimentary app for others to use.  However, whenever I try sharing my app with other people, they are unable to open it.

I am using OneDrive.  I can see which data connections each user has, and it appears that they all have access to the OneDrive folder.

I have tried sharing the app and changing the users' permissions, but it did no good.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/share-app

After you build a canvas app that addresses a business need, specify which users in your organization can run the app and which can modify and even reshare it. Specify each user by name, or specify a security group in Azure Active Directory. If everyone would benefit from your app, specify that your entire organization can run it.

You can only share your app in your organization.